# Load dropdowns from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to load a dropdown list from a stored procedure and I am not having any luck. I am new to coding so I could not even give you an educated guess as to what I am doing wrong. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub LoadDropDowns()
    Dim drData As SqlDataReader
    Dim liItem As ListItem
    lblError.Text = ""
    lblError2.Text = lblError.Text
    Dim aNames As ArrayList
    Dim sSQL As String = ""

    Try
        ddlEmployee.Items.Clear()
        liItem = New ListItem
        liItem.Value = drData("StaffID")
        liItem.Text = drData("Fullname")
        ddlEmployee.Items.Add(liItem)

        Try

            drData = ExecuteSQLReaderProc("dbo.FetchCWSSocialWorkers", "phemployee")

        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
        While drData.Read
            liItem = New ListItem
            liItem.Value = drData("StaffID")
            liItem.Text = drData("Fullname")
            ddlEmployee.Items.Add(liItem)

        End While
        ddlEmployee.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch myException As Exception
        lblError.Text = myException.Message
    Finally
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

the below code you can execute an SQL stored procedure and save the results to a range in your sheet.

```
Sub ImportStoreProcedure()

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Dim StoredProceedure As String
    StoredProceedure = "Stored_Proceedure_Name"

        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MACHINE\SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=CATALOGNAME;User ID=xx; Password=xxxxxxx; "

        rst.Open StoredProceedure, conn
        Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```